# How do I set Samsung Galaxy Device to run on APK?

Tags: android, debugging, device

I tried to follow Android Developer instructions to develop on my device (http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

In bulletin 3, (Windows USB Driver) I downloaded the driver and the
Windows Add New Hardware Wizard couldn't find the driver in the downloaded file.

what should I do? is it a configuration issue with my machine? how else can I install the driver?

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download kies and you'll get the drivers installed properly. Thats the easiest solution for you.

After that, set the USB Debugging mode on from your phone (Settings / Applications / Development), plug your phone in and hit F11 in Eclipse.
If you're not using Eclipse, get it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Galaxy S phone, downloading kies worked for me.

However, it did cause some strange recurring error when Windows7 started (I forget what the dialog was).  I fixed it by not having kies start on boot.